# Editing Build Settings in xcode 4

Tags: xcode4

I have been unable to work out how to edit build settings using the pop-up shown below.

[image]

I can enter multiple lines in the pop-up by clicking the '+'.  My questions are :-

1. What is the checkbox next to the setting used for?
2. Once I have entered one or more settings in the pop-up, how do I make them transfer to the setting I am editing.  There isn't a 'Save' button, and clicking off the pop-up closes it but doesn't seem to save the entered data.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete, check the checkbox and click "-".
To make a new one, click "+".
To save, click "Done".

Welcome to the Wonderful World of Apple UX.

Comment: Thanks, but there is no "Done" anywhere on the dialogue box

Comment: Yes, it would seem they removed the "Done" button in 4.3. So now check the checkbox on your new path(s) before closing the window, and then Xcode remembers what you just told it. Welcome to the Wonderful World of... oh, nevermind.

Comment: I was clicking the check box first and then editing the value and nothing saved...very confusing.  Thanks @Yusuf

Comment: What if there is no checkbox and no Done button? This is what I see when I try to change Valid Architectures.