# How to commit build settings in popover on Xcode

Tags: xcode4

In Xcode 4.3.1, I am having extreme difficulty whenever I try to change a build setting such as "Other Linker Flags".

If I double-click, a pop-up shows which ostensibly allows you to add/remove values.  However, there is no "done" button and all key combinations I've tried (enter/command-enter/etc...) fail to commit the values I've entered.

It is possible to enter a value without the pop-up by /slow/-double-clicking (WTF, Apple?!?) the edit line.  This works, but why the heck does is the pop-up the default double-click result when it seems to be totally useless, misleading and annoying?!?!

A similar question is [Editing Build Settings in xcode 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321507/editing-build-settings-in-xcode-4) but bugloaf's question of what to do when there is no "done button" remained unanswered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Editing Build Settings in xcode 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10321507/editing-build-settings-in-xcode-4)

Answer (score 0):

This is more to do with how to interact with popovers in OS X in general. "Transient" popovers force  you to *click* outside them to dismiss. Whatever changes you make inside them should always be "committed" by the time the popover is dismissed. This is standard Mac behavior.

So to answer the unanswered question: Click outside the popover to dismiss/commit.

As you ssuggested, you can slow-double-click (once to select, pause, once to begin editing cell) to edit text cells inline without the popover. This is also standard Mac behavior.

The double-click action is a secondary effect and can be taken to mean "give me a bigger editor for this field" - this seems to be just Xcode behavior. File bug reports if you think there should be a better mechanism. Be prepared to describe a better mechanism.

Comment: I did some more observing, and dismissing the popover sometimes commits the entered value (for "User Header Search Paths") and other times discards the value (for "Other Linker Flags") with zero explanation why.  Is this a bug or is there some esoteric criteria at work?  Either way, the behavior is damn frustrating.

Comment: I'd report this behavior as a bug.